# How to use ipw3945 on Ubuntu 9.04

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking, drivers, network-adapter

I am running Ubuntu 9.04 and I want to use ipw3945 instead of iwl3945.

I have disabled [iwl3945](http://linuxwireless.org/en/users/Drivers/iwl3945):

```
`cat /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf | tail -3`
> blacklist iwl3945  
> blacklist mac8021
```

How can I use [iwp3945](http://ipw3945.sourceforge.net/) instead?

(Kernal is 2.6.28-16-generic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Downloaded the latest as follows:

**Note:**

> From [ipw3945.sourceforge.net](http://ipw3945.sourceforge.net/)

- ipw3945 binary microcode
- ipw3945 binary user space regulatory daemon ([ipw3945d_1.7.22-5_i386.deb](http://snapshot.debian.net/archive/2007/08/06/debian/pool/non-free/i/ipw3945d/ipw3945d_1.7.22-5_i386.deb))
- ipw3945 driver source

Obtained the following patches (to use the above on the 2.6.28.16-generic kernel and`>`):

- ipw3945-1.2.2-kernel-2.6.24.patch
- ipw3945-1.2.2-kernel-2.6.27.patch

**Installation:**

- Ran dpkg -i ipw3945d_1.7.22-5_i386.deb
- touch /etc/modprobe.d/00local.conf

  - Add to the above file:

    > install iwl3945 /bin/true
- Extracted ipw3945-ucode, change directory and copy ipw3945-ucode to /lib/firmware
- Extracted ipw3945 driver, change directory and patched as follows:

  - patch ipw3945.h ipw3945-1.2.2-kernel-2.6.24.patch
  - patch ipw3945.h ipw3945-1.2.2-kernel-2.6.27.patch
  - **Important:** open Makefile (using vi or other) and add `CONFIG_LOCALVERSION=""`
  - make SHELL=/bin/bash
  - make SHELL=/bin/bash install
  - reboot or attempt modprobe ipw3945:

`modprobe ipw3945`

`* Starting ipw3945 regulatory daemon ipw3945d                           [ OK ]`

Answer (score 0):

By downloading the iwp3945 tarball, there's a INSTALL file inside that will give you the details.  It may not be a step-by-step install in your case, but should be close.  Just read the whole thing to get a feel for it.